# What are some compatible Polaroid film type replacements for the Fuji FP100c?

Tags: medium-format, polaroid, instant-camera, mamiya

For my Mamiya RZ67 I got one of these old polaroid backs, but I made the mistake of not checking if there are still films available. What I read so far is that it takes Fuji FP100c (and similar) Polaroid films, however they are no longer manufactured and ridiculously expensive (something like >$100 for one pack...).

Are there any modern remakes available that the Polaroid back will eat? Like the Polaroid 600 films? I found already modern backs that eat Instax films too, however I'm curious if I can use the Polaroid back or should sell it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FP100c is a peel-apart film. Integral films like the Polaroid 600 cannot be used with a peel-apart back.

There is only one peel-apart film currently manufactured, but it's hand-made and therefore rather expensive, and I'm not sure whether it would be compatible with your specific film back or not: https://the.supersense.com/products/one-instant (note that 1 pack = 1 picture)

Comment: One Instant is designed to be compatible with existing Type 100 (4x3 peel-apart) cameras and backs -- for all the good that does at something like $15 a print...

Comment: Oof, ok, thank you, will sell the Polaroid back then.